# Can plain Javascript objects have events?

Tags: javascript, object, events

Can plain Javascript objects have event attached to them? Say something like this:

```
obj = new Object();
obj.addEventListener('doSomething', foo, true);
```

I know i can do this with jQuery, but is it possible without any library?

Comment: Who would call such event actions?

Comment: Yeah... So much, so fast!
Thanks people!

@Gumbo say you can have something like xmpp library and you can trigger events on that lib/object (like "connected", "disconnected" etc). And you want some actions to be executed when event occure... That is why I ask about events.

Comment: Browsers can not do it natively, however, you can use [my EventEmitter class](https://github.com/Wolfy87/EventEmitter) to do this.

Just putting it here for anyone else stumbling upon this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You'll have to implement your own functionality for that, but that's not very hard.

```
var obj = {
    events: {},
    addEventListener: function(eventName, handler) {
        if(!(eventName in this.events))
            this.events[eventName] = [];

        this.events[eventName].push(handler);
    },

    raiseEvent: function(eventName, args) {
        var currentEvents = this.events[eventName];
        if(!currentEvents) return;

        for(var i = 0; i < currentEvents.length; i++) {
           if(typeof currentEvents[i] == 'function') {
              currentEvents[i](args);
           }
        }
    },

    click: function() {
        // custom 'click' function. when this is called, you do whatever you
        // want 'click' to do. and then raise the event:

        this.raiseEvent('onClick');
    }
};
```

Comment: Yeah. Its not that hard. But i'd like to be sure i have to. Thanks!

Comment: This answer is outdated, scroll down to mine for a more up-to-date one.

Answer (score 6):

No.

However, you could make your own implementation by writing `addEventListener` and other functions and storing a list of handlers for each event.

For example: (Untested)

```
function addEventListener(name, handler) {
    if (!this.events) this.events = {};
    if (!this.events[name]) this.events[name] = [];
    this.events[name].push(handler);
}

function removeEventListener(name, handler) {
    if (!this.events) return;
    if (!this.events[name]) return;
    for (var i = this.events[name].length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        if (this.events[name][i] == handler)
            this.events[name].splice(i, 1);
}

function raiseEvent(name, args) {
    if (!this.events) return;
    if (!this.events[name]) return;
    for (var i = 0; i < this.events[name].length; i++)
        this.events[name][i].apply(this, args);
}


var obj = ...;
obj.addEventListener = addEventListener;
obj.removeEventListener = removeEventListener;
obj.raiseEvent = raiseEvent;
```

Comment: this is a more solid effort than my own, so +1 for that.

Answer (score 2):

Not directly but you add the required `publish/subscribe` infrastructure to any one of them.

Answer (score 2):

As of recent, this is actually possible!

It doesn't have amazing browser support however. See "EventTarget() constructor" part of this graph: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget#Browser_compatibility

Or look at this graph which only contains the relevant row: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/EventTarget#Browser_compatibility

In either case, all you need to do is have your class extend EventTarget, and ensure that you call `super()` in the constructor. After that's done, you can dispatch and listen for events like on DOM objects.

Sample code:

```
class EventDispatcher extends EventTarget {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }

    dispatch_event() {
        this.dispatchEvent(new Event("important-notification"));
    }
}

const event_dispatcher = new EventDispatcher();

event_dispatcher.addEventListener("important-notification", function() {
    console.log("Something important happened!");
});

event_dispatcher.dispatch_event();
```

Answer (score 1):

No. `addEventListener` is a feature of the DOM, not JS.

Comment: I know. This is why I say "somethng like..." ;)

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll find that in plain JavaScript, it's only DOM objects that can have events.

Comment: Specifically, you can have events on objects that implement the `EventTarget` interface from DOM Level 2 Events. That includes `Element` and `Document` from the DOM, but also `window`, `XMLHttpRequest` and `WebSocket`; probably more I have forgotten.

Answer (score 1):

No, the only thing that JavaScript objects have is properties. The values of these properties may be:

- A primitive value
- An object (including a function object)

Answer (score 0):

No, not to the extent that you can add an event handler to any object.  You could write your own event system for objects though, if you're writing some sort of API or library for other scripts to interact with.

Answer (score 0):

You can define an addEventListener method to collect all the listener objects, and your code can call them anytime. It's just OO programming. Define the addXListener, add the object passed as parameter somewhere, and when something happens you call it's methods.

Yes.

But remember that UI events are those defined by HTML/Javascript so what you'd be programming will be only for your "obj" object to alert about YOUR events.

By example:

```
FunnyProcessor
+ addStartListener(...)
+ addProcessingListener(...)
+ addEndListener(...)
+ doStuff()
```

and doSuff will call first the start listeners, next do some loop and for each iteration call processing listeners, and at the end call end listeners.

Comment: Your FunnyProcessor reminds me of an Observable... and the post being from 2010, it's an Observable before it was cool.