# Adding event listeners to classes(ES6)

Tags: javascript, html, oop, ecmascript-6, polymorphism

I am trying to embrace good OOP practices in ES6 and am struggling with event listeners. It seems wrong at times to put them in the class but how else would you handle several classes and passing a class to a listener? Here's the code I always use inside some generic class.

```
addEventListener(domEvent, functionRef, domElement=window, bubbles=false){
    domElement.addEventListener(domEvent, functionRef.bind(this), bubbles);
}
```

Is there a style guide somewhere for this kind of stuff? There never seems to be a, "right", answer for front end web js.

Comment: Honestly, it seems like you're just rewriting the existing API here. Why not just store a reference to the element and call `addEventListener` directly? `constructor(element) { element.addEventListener("click", this.elementClick.bind(this)); }`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can plain Javascript objects have events?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2086956/can-plain-javascript-objects-have-events)